# How to get UserRequest data from itop REST API

Tags: go, http-post

I got this error when I used Go's standard `http` library to send post requests to the itop rest api.

```
{"code":5,"message":"Error: Missing parameter 'auth_user'"}
```

**this is the request data model:**

```golang
package main

// UserRequest structure
type Base struct {
    Code    int    `json:"code"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

type Fileds struct {
    RequestType            string `json:"request_type"`
    ServiceSubcategoryName string `json:"servicesubcategory_name"`
    Urgency                string `json:"urgency"`
    Origin                 string `json:"origin"`
    CallerIdFriendlyName   string `json:"caller_id_friendlyname"`
    Impact                 string `json:"impact"`
    Title                  string `json:"title"`
    Description            string `json:"description"`
}

type ResponseContent struct {
    Code    int    `json:"code"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Class   string `json:"class"`
    Key     string `json:"key"`
    Filed   Fileds `json:"fields"`
}

type Response struct {
    Base
    Object map[string]ResponseContent `json:"objects"`
}

// Request api data struct
type RequestData struct {
    Operation    string `json:"operation"`
    Class        string `json:"class"`
    Key          string `json:"key"`
    OutPutFields string `json:"output_fields"`
}

type RequestAuth struct {
    AuthUser string `json:"auth_user"`
    AuthPwd  string `json:"auth_pwd"`
    // JsonData RequestData `json:"json_data"`
    JsonData string `json:"json_data"`
}
```

the main function:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

const (
    ITOP_URL = `http://192.168.17.22:8096/itop/webservices/rest.php?version=1.3`
)

func main() {
    request_auth := new(RequestAuth)
    request_data := new(RequestData)
    request_auth.AuthUser = "admin"
    request_auth.AuthPwd = "goodjob@123"

    request_data.Operation = "core/get"
    request_data.Class = "UserRequest"
    request_data.Key = "SELECT UserRequest WHERE operational_status = \"ongoing\""
    request_data.OutPutFields = "request_type,servicesubcategory_name,urgency,origin,caller_id_friendlyname,impact,title,description"
    req_data, err := json.Marshal(request_data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    request_auth.JsonData = string(req_data)

    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(request_auth)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    reader := bytes.NewReader(jsonData)
    result := Post(ITOP_URL, reader)
    fmt.Println(string(result))
}

func Post(url string, reader *bytes.Reader) []byte {
    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, reader)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    request.Header.Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(reader.Len()))
    client := http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    respBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    return respBytes
}
```

But when I use Python's requests library, I don't have this problem. I think requests has done some processing?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests, json

HOST = "http://192.168.17.22:8096/itop/webservices/rest.php?version=1.3"

json_str = json.dumps({
    "operation":
    "core/get",
    "class":
    "UserRequest",
    "key":
    "SELECT UserRequest WHERE operational_status = 'ongoing'",
    "output_fields":
    "request_type,servicesubcategory_name,urgency,origin,caller_id_friendlyname,impact,title,description",
})
json_data = {
    "auth_user": "admin",
    "auth_pwd": "goodjob@123",
    "json_data": json_str
}


# secure_rest_services
def get():
    r = requests.post(HOST, data=json_data)
    return r


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = get()
    print(result.json())
```

output:

```
{'objects': {'UserRequest::7': {'code': 0, 'message': '', 'class': 'UserRequest', 'key': '7', 'fields': {'request_type': 'service_request', 'servicesubcategory_name': '钉钉权限开通', 'urgency': '4', 'origin': 'portal', 'caller_id_friendlyname': 'x 阿里合作项目负责人', 'impact': '1', 'title': '溫江|A-222|wb-xxxxxxxx', 'description': '<p>this is a test approve...</p>'}}, 'UserRequest::6': {'code': 0, 'message': '', 'class': 'UserRequest', 'key': '6', 'fields': {'request_type': 'service_request', 'servicesubcategory_name': '钉钉权限开通', 'urgency': '3', 'origin': 'portal', 'caller_id_friendlyname': 'x 阿里合作项目负责人', 'impact': '1', 'title': '高朋|Xa-111|wb-xx111111', 'description': '<p>這是一個測試用的用戶需求</p>'}}}, 'code': 0, 'message': 'Found: 2'}
```

**When I override Python requests' default headers, I return the same result as Go.**

```py
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
requests.post(url, data=json_data, headers=headers)
```

Perhaps there is a problem with the request **headers**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post data to api with url.Values, the python `requests` library uses from mode by default.

Itop only accepts form format